# Bootstrap Button Dropdown Not Working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

I am using Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS to write the front end code. I want to have a button that when clicked, shows two options- sort method 1, and sort method 2. I cannot get my Bootstrap split button to work correctly. The dropdown menu is not showing up at all.

Code:

```
<th>
  <a ng-click="sort = method1" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> Numbers </a> 
  <a class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-md" data-toggle = "dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </a>
  <ul class ="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a ng-click="sort = method1" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> Sorting Method 1 </a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="sort = method2" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> Sorting Method 2 </a></li>
  </ul>
</th>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing many components that are necessary for this dropdown button to work. Please refer to the documentation [dropdown buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns).

You don't have your button inside a `btn-group`, you're using `a` tags instead of `button`, and didn't have `type="button"` set (because of the `a` tags).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<th>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" ng-click="sort = method1">Numbers</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a ng-click="sort = method1" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> Sorting Method 1 </a>

      </li>
      <li><a ng-click="sort = method2" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> Sorting Method 2 </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

It it set to screen reader only with class sr-only do you see the caret?